# Sum of two independent geometric random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X and Y be independent random variables,

$  P(X = k) = P(Y = k) = p(1 - p)^{k-1} $

How do you show that the pmf of $ Z = X + Y $, is negative binomial, and how do you find

$ P(X = Y) $?

Comment: This is the probability that the $k$th trial is the first success. You would have to use convolutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$P(Z=r)=\Sigma_{k=1}^r P(X=k)P(Y=r-k)$

$P(X=Y)=\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X=k)P(Y=k)$

I am assuming $k$ is a positive integer. Otherwise, the summations need to be modified accordingly.

Comment: Thats great! One question, is P(Y = r - k) = p(1-p)^r-k-1?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 17):

While Timothy Wagner's answer is correct, I thought you might like to see another way to answer your first question.

Often the simplest way to prove that the sum of independent random variables has a particular distribution is to use [moment-generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function).  This is because 1) if $X$ and $Y$ are independent with mgf's $M_X(t)$ and $M_Y(t)$, then $M_{X+Y}(t) = M_X(t) M_Y(t)$ and 2) moment-generating functions (when they exist) characterize distributions.

Applying this to your problem, a geometric $(p)$ random variable has mgf $$\frac{pe^t}{1 - (1-p)e^t}.$$

Thus $$M_{X+Y}(t) = \left(\frac{pe^t}{1 - (1-p)e^t}\right)^{2}.$$
Since this is the mgf of a negative binomial random variable, $X+Y$ must have a negative binomial distribution.

(There are different conventions for defining negative binomial and geometric random variables, so depending on the convention used in a particular reference the mgf's there may be slightly different from the ones I give here.)