# Probability generating function, moment generating function and characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory

1. I learned that for any distribution,
   its characteristic function always
   exist while its probability
   generating function and  moment
   generating function may not.

   I was wondering if that means
   characteristic function can be
   useful anywhere the other two are?
2. Taking into account the existence issue among others, what are some cases, all can be
   useful? What are some cases, one or
   two are useful? In other words, I
   would like to know when to choose
   which tool solve problems.

   For example, probability generating function can be used to solve recurrence relation for discrete distribution. Can the other two also be?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: This might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14714/characteristic-functions-and-motivations/14720#14720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on Mike's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14714/characteristic-functions-and-motivations/14720#14720).

For a (nonnegative) random variable $X$ having distribution $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)$, it is often convenient to use the Laplace transform:
$$
{\rm E}[e^{ - uX} ] = \int_{[0,\infty )} {e^{ - ux} \mu ({\rm d}x)}, \;\; u \geq 0,
$$ 
which is always defined and bounded from above by $1$.