# Fundamental Difference Between GF, MGF, and PGF

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

After taking two courses in Probability Theory and Mathematical Statistics, I have wondered what is the fundamental difference between a Moment Generating Function, a Probability Generating Function, and Generating Functions that are used to solve problems in combinatorics?

Specifically, I understand that a MGF is used to calculate the moments of either a discrete or continuous distribution and then build that distribution by summing these moments (similar to how a Taylor Series works). A PGF is a more general version of a MGF but can only be applied to discrete distributions. As for Generating Functions, in several combinatorics books I have read, there is no mention of moments so I'm assuming a Generating Function is different from MGF and PGF.

Comment: A generating function is just whenever you encode a sequence of numbers as coefficients of a power series. In particular, the moment generating function is the moments encoded as the coefficients of a power series, which happens to just be what you get when you take the Laplace transform of the PDF (similar to how the characteristic function is basically the Fourier transform). The PGF is just another generating function but where the coefficients of the power series encode the discrete probability mass at each point (when all possible states are enumerated). Is this all you were after?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14714/characteristic-functions-and-motivations

Comment: For example, if I have a sequence of numbers $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, then the generating function for that sequence is just $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$. Since each of the $x^k$ can be thought of in some sense as different components in this infinite-dimensional vector space, the whole idea of a generating function is really just as a different way of formally writing out a sequence. I suppose every formal power series can be thought of as the generating function for the sequence of its coefficients and vice-versa.

Comment: @JackCrawford That helped immensely, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generating function is just whenever you encode a sequence of numbers as coefficients of a power series. In particular, the moment generating function is the moments encoded as the coefficients of a power series, which happens to just be what you get when you take the Laplace transform of the PDF (similar to how the characteristic function is basically the Fourier transform). The PGF is just another generating function but where the coefficients of the power series encode the discrete probability mass at each point (when all possible states are enumerated).

Since each of the x-values can be thought of in some sense as different components in this infinite-dimensional vector space, the whole idea of a generating function is really just as a different way of formally writing out a sequence. I suppose every formal power series can be thought of as the generating function for the sequence of its coefficients and vice-versa.