# probability and generating functions...motivations and analogies

Tags: probability, soft-question, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions, motivation

I have a question similar in spirit to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14714/characteristic-functions-and-motivations/14720#14720).

In essence, what does a generating function (moment, probability, characteristic, other?) "do" to a random variable $X$, and how are the generating functions related? Does it:

1. allow us to break up the function $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ into component functions with interpretable "coefficients" (like a Fourier transform), or
2. can it be seen as a particular way of approximating the distribution function $F_X(x)$, or
3. is there an interpretation for how the moments of $X$ relate to the generating functions (to motivate "differentiate and evaluate at $t=0$"), or
4. something else? It feels like I'm trying to take a shortcut to interpreting these things without having taken functional analysis / more math, so I'm curious if these intuitions are totally off.

---

For (1), form the Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), "generating functions" are used to turn encode an infinite sequence into coefficients in a formal power series. I'm wondering if there's a way of explaining the Fourier transform of the density of $X$ in terms of something that relates to viewing $X$ as a function and approximating it with basis functions, etc. If there is such an interpretation, is there a motivation for the "coefficients" and working in an "algebraic"/frequency domain?

Similarly, for (2), from the Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Introduction) for "characteristic functions", it draws a distinction between the distribution function
$$
F_X(x) = E \left[ \mathbf{1}\{X\leq x\} \right]
$$
and the characteristic function
$$
\psi_X(t) = E \left[ e^{itX} \right].
$$
It hadn't occurred to me to think of it this way, but is there any way of thinking about $\psi_X$ as a smooth approximation to the indicator function for approximating $F_X$ with some relation between the arguments $x$ and $t$ (disregarding $i$, so I guess considering the mgf)? I've seen the idea of a generating function be used in convex optimization to [bound](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/SIOPT_Bern_2006.pdf) probabilities, which is different, but I'm wondering if there's some connection.)

Finally for (3), I don't have any far-fetched hypotheses like in (1-2), but I'm just curious if there's some motivation for this beyond "it falls out of the properties of generating functions for sequences".

Answer (score 2):

For a continuous random variable $X$ with a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) $f(x)$, the moment generating function is exactly the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of $f(x)$ (up to a sign), and similarly the characteristic function is exactly the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of $f(x)$ (again up to a sign, and possibly some other normalizing factors depending on conventions). These are both somewhat sophisticated mathematical operations and ultimately I think there's no substitute for understanding them beyond working through some theorems and examples and seeing how they behave.

A basic property of both of these transforms is that they intertwine [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) and multiplication, and for random variables convolution corresponds to adding independent copies, so we get a basic and important property of both the MGF and the characteristic function, which is that (I'll only state this property for the characteristic function) if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then

$$\phi_{X+Y}(t) = \mathbb{E}(\exp(it(X+Y)) = \mathbb{E}(\exp(itX) \exp(itY)) = \mathbb{E}(\exp(itX)) \mathbb{E}(\exp(itY)) = \phi_X(t) \phi_Y(t).$$

This makes the characteristic function very well-suited to understanding sums of independent random variables, which is responsible e.g. for its role in one of the standard proofs of the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

One way to build intuition for these more sophisticated transforms is to start with the simpler [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) that arise in combinatorics (which can sometimes be turned into probability generating functions). You can check out, for example, Wilf's *[generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html)*. As a simple example, the function $(1 + x)^n$ is both the generating function of the binomial coeficients (by the binomial theorem) and also produces, upon division by $2^n$, the probability generating function $\left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{2} \right)^n$ of a sum of $n$ independent [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) random variables (the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)). This readily gives the MGF $\left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{e^t}{2} \right)^n$ as well as the characteristic function $\left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{e^{it}}{2} \right)^n$, although interpreting these is more mysterious.

I also found [these notes by Terence Tao on concentration of measure](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Wilf's book! It's interesting that some generating functions from combinatorics can be turned into pgfs but others can't

Comment: By the way, when you say that the characteristic function is exactly the fourier transform of the pdf $f$, is there any way to interpret the "coefficients" of the fourier transform? Or am I making some sort of mistake?

Comment: @jjjjjj: I don't know what to say about this beyond statements that can be made about Fourier transforms in general: they tell you the "frequencies" of the pdf.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks! Yep was just wondering if frequencies of the pdf have any useful interpretation or if they show up in other places