# probability density of sum of iid's

Tags: probability

If $X_1 ,X_2,X_3 \dots X_n   $ are geometrically distributed iid's with parameter p. How do I calculate the probability density function of $ S_n = X_1+X_2 \dots + X_n$

Comment: Use induction on this maybe? : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10318/sum-of-two-independent-geometric-random-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that $S_n=m$ is the probability that the $n$-th success occurs on the $m$-th trial. This is the probability that there are exactly $n-1$ successes in the first $m-1$ trials, followed by a success on the $m$-th trial. Thus
$$\Pr(S_n=m)=\binom{m-1}{n-1}p^{m-1}(1-p)^{m-n} p.$$
This expression can be simplified slightly.

It is required that $m\ge n$. Note that we have obtained the probability **distribution** function of $S_n$.